# Qual a função em PHP que retorna a mesma coisa que "(char) inteiro"?

Tags: php, c#

Estou com um código para converter de C# para PHP. Esse código tem uma conversão de inteiro para char, e não estou conseguindo obter o mesmo resultado.

Obs.: Eu sei que PHP não é fortemente tipado, mas na versão 7.1 (que estou usando) ele já trabalha com tipagem.

Código em C# ([link para simular](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0lg5Pq)):

```
using System;
    public class Program {
    public static void Main()
    {   
        gerar(89012, 123456);
    }

    public static void gerar(int valor, int codigo) {
        char[] arr = new char[8];

        int v = Convert.ToInt32(valor); 
        arr[0] = (char)(codigo >> 23); 
        arr[1] = (char)((codigo >> 15) & 0xFF);
        arr[2] = (char)((codigo >> 7) & 0xFF);
        arr[3] = (char)((v >> 7) & 0xFF);
        arr[4] = (char)(v & 0xFF);

        Console.WriteLine("arr[0]: " + arr[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[1]: " + arr[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[2]: " + arr[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[3]: " + arr[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[4]: " + arr[4]);
    }
}
```

Já utilizei neste código convertido pra PHP ...

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$codigo = intval(123456);
$v = intval(89012);

$arr = [];
$codigo = intval(123456);
$v = intval(89012);
$arr[0] = ($codigo >> 23); 
$arr[1] = (($codigo >> 15) & 0xFF);
$arr[2] = (($codigo >> 7) & 0xFF);
$arr[3] = (($v >> 7) & 0xFF);
$arr[4] = ($v & 0xFF);

var_dump($arr[0]);
var_dump($arr[1]);
var_dump($arr[2]);
var_dump($arr[3]);
var_dump($arr[4]);
die;
```

... as funções:

- chr()
- mb_chr()
- (string)
- strval()
- mb_convert_encoding() (tanto para UTF-16, UTF-8...)

E até agora nenhuma printou o mesmo retorno....

Comment: Qual é o retorno esperado e o que os seus testes retornaram?

Comment: WriteLine do C#: 

arr[0]: 
arr[1]: 
arr[2]: Ä
arr[3]: ·
arr[4]: ´

var_dump do PHP depende da função que usar mas nenhuma delas volta a mesma coisa.

Comment: @bfavaretto se você usar http://phptester.net/ e https://dotnetfiddle.net/ para simular os códigos acima da pra pegar bem certo os retornos.

Comment: Se não me engano o C# vai usar UTF-16 nesse cast. Tente `mb_chr ($valor, 'UTF-16')`

Comment: Estou pensando no que pode ser, o problema não é a conversão, é a manipulação de bits. O original já parece ruim e tenho minhas dúvidas se faz o que devia fazer, pode ser um problema XY.

Comment: @bfavaretto TOP! Deu certo usando UTF-8. Comenta ai que eu coloco como resposta! Valeu!

Comment: Isabela: Se/quando eu entender o motivo de ter funcionado com UTF-8 eu posto uma resposta :)

Comment: Não sei como pode ter funcionando, sem a conversão já dá errado: https://ideone.com/1UEwbU

Comment: Fiz mais uns testes ([PHP](https://ideone.com/p1DK0D), [C#](https://ideone.com/fN3yVp)). Acho que essas ferramentas dão a saída em UTF-16 (no caso do C# e de um dos meus testes em PHP), mas o browser vai sempre interpretar como UTF-8. @Maniero

Comment: @maniero, o código está com erro de sintaxe. Já corrigi na pergunta mas não deve ter atualizado ainda. Depois dessa correção o mb_chr() funciona.

Comment: @bfvaretto não fui a fundo pra entender ainda, mas como não vou isar a saída pro usuário está tranquilo. Vou usar para mais cálculos que não vinha ao caso postar. Inclusive o erro na sintaxe que eu falei pro Maniero aconteceu exatamente pelos ctrl+c do c# xD