# Como faço para converter os valores do array php para o tipo "uint" do C#?

Tags: php, c#, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Preciso pegar cada valor do índice do array e converter para ele retornar a mesma coisa que retorna no C# quando usamos a função (uint).

```
<?php 
$arr = [];
$codigo = intval(123456);
$v = intval(89012);

$arr[0] = ($codigo >> 23); 
$arr[1] = (($codigo >> 15) & 0xFF);
$arr[2] = (($codigo >> 7) & 0xFF);
$arr[3] = (($v >> 7) & 0xFF);
$arr[4] = ($v & 0xFF);

$arr[0] = ($arr[0] == 0) ? '' : mb_chr($arr[0], 'UTF-8');
$arr[1] = ($arr[1] == 0) ? '' : mb_chr($arr[1], 'UTF-8');
$arr[2] = ($arr[2] == 0) ? '' : mb_chr($arr[2], 'UTF-8');
$arr[3] = ($arr[3] == 0) ? '' : mb_chr($arr[3], 'UTF-8');
$arr[4] = ($arr[4] == 0) ? '' : mb_chr($arr[4], 'UTF-8');

//converter para uint cada índice do array $arr

var_dump($arr[0]);
var_dump($arr[1]);
var_dump($arr[2]);
var_dump($arr[3]);
var_dump($arr[4]);
die;
?>
```

Em C# o código seria assim:

```
using System;
public class Program {
    public static void Main(){   
        gerar(89012, 123456);
    }

    public static void gerar(int valor, int codigo) {
        char[] arr = new char[8];

        int v = Convert.ToInt32(valor); 
        arr[0] = (char)(codigo >> 23); 
        arr[1] = (char)((codigo >> 15) & 0xFF);
        arr[2] = (char)((codigo >> 7) & 0xFF);
        arr[3] = (char)((v >> 7) & 0xFF);
        arr[4] = (char)(v & 0xFF);

        Console.WriteLine("Valor a ser convertido: ");
        Console.WriteLine("arr[0]: " + arr[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[1]: " + arr[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[2]: " + arr[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[3]: " + arr[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[4]: " + arr[4]);

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nConvertido: ");
        Console.WriteLine("arr[0]: " + (uint) arr[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[1]: " + (uint) arr[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[2]: " + (uint) arr[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[3]: " + (uint) arr[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("arr[4]: " + (uint) arr[4]);
    }
}
```

A saída do C# (e eu preciso que seja do PHP também) é:

Valor:

arr[0]:

arr[1]:

arr[2]: Ä

arr[3]: ·

arr[4]: ´

Convertido:

arr[0]: 0

arr[1]: 3

arr[2]: 196

arr[3]: 183

arr[4]: 180

Comment: PHP não suporta isto, não dá para fazer essas traduções de algoritmo dessa forma por isso ontem eu disse que o problema era XY, a solução é saber o que deveria fazer e construir de outra forma. Eu nem sei se isso é realmente necessário, mas estou vendo sói um pedação da questão.

Comment: @Maniero, ontem, na outra pergunta você disse que o código não estava funcionando (e não estava, te respondi lá), mas aquele problema foi resolvido e está funcionando. Se este eu vou conseguir fazer, ai é outro caso. Eu acredito que tenha uma forma de resolver, só não encontrei ainda :)

Comment: Pela conversa entre vc e o @Maniero da a entender que há outra pergunta relacionada com essa já resolvida. Referencia ela nesta pergunta para que outras pessoas que acessem esta pergunta tenham mais contexto.

Comment: @DNick não acredito que faça muita diferença, mas segue o link. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423776/qual-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-php-que-retorna-a-mesma-coisa-que-char-inteiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não consegue converter até porque o valor **Unit** do C# é um valor especifico do próprio construtor e compilador da linguagem assim como são alguams coisas no PHP também (Iterator, Exceptions entre outras).

Quando você necessita ou se necessitará no futuro novamente fazer comunicação entre 2 linguagens diferentes é sempre aconselhavel utilizar-se o padrão JSON para que se passe os valores que é globalmente suportado por quase todas as linguagens modernas e que tem constantes atualizações hoje em dia (principalmente linguagens de ambito web).

Outra forma também de se fazer essa comunicação entre linguagens e verificar os tipos primitivos, por exemplo, independentemente do compilador ou engine que as 2 linguagens que você está utilizando para se comunicarem os tipos primitivos são totalmente inflexiveis, por exemplo, uma Integer no C# é a mesma coisa que uma Integer no PHP a unica variação máxima que você poderá ter entre elas é o tipo scalar e quando bytes ela suportão, but em grande parte do tempo funciona muito bem strings por exemplo, só floats pode ser um pouco complicado porque linguagens como Python que fora desenvolvida para ambitos totalmente voltado de exatas e matematica pura os numeros tem seus próprios tipos scalares, but em grande maioria eles se entendem muito bem.

Comment: Fábio, realmente se tivessem usado os tipos primitivos eu seria uma pessoa feliz. Mas esse código está embarcado em vários equipamentos. Então eu não tenho muita opção de trocar o cálculo... Vou acabar fazendo em C++ e mandar buscar lá... acho que vai ser a melhor opção.

Comment: Mesmo sendo embarcado os tipos primitivos eles não se alteram, você só precisa tomar cuidado com o tipo do Float que ele é o que mais dá problemas em transições de ambientes de compilação.